# Change value to use for function based on selected option value?

Tags: jquery, user-defined-functions

I have a data table footer filter to filter only GET and POST requests from log records. I need to make the request to URL with parameter value 0 or 1 respectively because 0 and 1 is the data in database.

I tried selecting with jQuery the value of selected option from the select element by id.

```
if (column == 4) {
  $('#method-filter').html(availableMethodsHtml);
  $('#method-filter').on('change', function() {
    var keyword = $(this).val()
    if (keyword == 'GET') {
      dyntable_Logs.columns([4]).search('0').draw()
    } else { // POST
      dyntable_Logs.columns([4]).search('1').draw()
    }
  })
}
```

I expect this to send 0 or 1 to parameter value but it sends the value of the selected option instead. How can I solve this? Thanks!